# How to flatten an Ansible list of lists and write out to file - IOS / Nexus (nxos)

Tags: ios, list, loops, ansible, nexus

```
ANSIBLE LOOPS
=============
```

I have the following tasks that I need to write the results out to text file. Reg yields a "list of lists". I can only seem to get what I want using a Jinja2 templating loop style. Is there another more 'elegant' way to accomplish this using the "with_list:" command or some other technique?

```
- name: Show Commands
  nxos_command:
    provider: "{{ provider }}"
    commands:
       - show version | include bin
       - show ip int brief
       - show ip route
       - show run | include logging
       - show snmp host

  register: reg
- debug: var=reg.stdout_lines


- copy:
    content: |
      {% for line in reg.stdout %}
        {{ line }}

      {% endfor %}
    dest: ./{{ CRQ }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}_post_{{ CRQ }}.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [join](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#id7) to convert it to string:

```
- copy:
    content: '{{ reg.stdout | join("\n") }}'
    dest: ./{{ CRQ }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}_post_{{ CRQ }}.txt
```

Comment: `stdout` and `stdout_lines` work differently for network modules and standard modules (like `command`), for network modules `stdout` is a list of lines (like `stdout_lines` for `command`) and `stdout_lines` is a list of lists.

Comment: That's perfect Konstantin. Work's great. I'd like to add a new line after each command is run, not sure if that is also possible...

Comment: you mean `join("\n\n")`?

Comment: I actually tried that, it doesn't seem to work, it just gives me the text \n\n between commands like this --  

       * master (synced), # master (unsynced), + selected, - candidate, ~ 
      configured\n\nlogging buffered 16384 debugging
       logging console notifications
       logging enable